# Working with struts in FF3.5

Tags: java, jquery, struts

I had created a web application using `struts2` and it works fine in *firefox 3.6* but not in *3.5*
Library files used:

```
Struts 2 core - commons-io-1.3.2.jar  
Struts 2 core - commons-logging-1.1.jar  
Struts 2 core - commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar  
Struts 2 core - freemarker-2.3.13.jar  
Struts 2 core - sturts2-core-2.1.6.jar  
Struts 2 core - ognl-2.6.11.jar  
Struts 2 core - xwork-2.1.2.jar  
Struts 2 core - log4j-1.2.9.jar  
xwork-core-2.1.6.jar  
struts2-jquery-plugin-2.3.0.jar  
struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
```

Server used - `Glassfish V3`
Also I had used `jquery javascript library v1.4.2`

Can anyone please help me to find why its not working and what should i do to make it work in *FF3.5*?
 I had included two files:

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%><br>
<%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%><br>
```

Only my s: tags are working but not sj:  tags

Comment: You are not describing *what* is not working.

Comment: Its a web application and I found many problems - json types of select box is not working and also datepicker, even links are not working

Comment: @jones - Code examples would be nice.  Unfortunately, I have yet to meet any mind-readers here ;)  Perhaps you can post an example of what isn't working?

Comment: This is the select box am using                                   <s:url id="load_projects" action="populateEntry"/>            <sj:select id="Login_timesheetDaily_projectName" href="%{load_projects}" name="projectName" headerValue="-- Please Select --" headerKey="0" list="projectNameList" listKey="projectCode" listValue="name" value="--Please Select--" onChangeTopics="load_task_phase" formIds="timesheet_en" /> It should populate when form is loading but it comes as an empty select box

Comment: @jones this is not going to lead anywhere. You need to isolate specific problems and error messages, one at a time, and ask specifically about those.

Comment: This gives really nothing to work with. It's like having a flat tire and telling the car mechanican in the garage "My car doesn't work" and nothing more. Try to describe problems and ask questions the smart way. Start here: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Am sorry am new to forums. The problem is <sj:> tags (struts2 jquery)are not working in fire fox 3.5

Comment: @jones - Please "edit" your original question so you can properly format the code so it's readable.  Put yourself in our shoes.  Would you be able to help someone who showed you something you couldn't read?  Look below your question for the "edit" button.

Comment: Right. What exactly happens instead? What do you see in HTML source? How about other browsers? Etc. Get yourself through the link I gave you in my previous comment. Note that in the average forum you would just be ignored if you ask questions that way :)

Comment: I'l try to explain myself clearly. My html view is fine but the problem is the struts 2 jquery tag is not performing its backend function(Its not performing its java function). so there is no value to be displayed by the select box.

Comment: @jones, if you dont give some clues how in the world do you expect anyone to figure out whats wrong. What exactly is not working ? There are a million things that could be wrong and you have not spent the time to help us help you.

Comment: Please isolate your question to specific problems, complete with code examples and descriptions of what is going wrong.

Comment: Is Javascript disabled in your FF 3.5? Do you use FF 3.6 only Javascripts? Have you errors in your console or FireBug? Without more specific information we can't help...

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild stab in the dark, but all the Struts examples I've seen have the attributes for the taglibs in a different order (uri ahead of prefix):

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-jquery-tags" prefix="sj" %>
```

Maybe it expects to parse the attributes in a specific order? It would help if you'd posted some of the logs / output from your web container.